# Receiving error in pycharm that older version chrome driver will not support my newer version browser:

Tags: google-chrome, driver

Receiving error in pycharm that older version chrome driver will not support my newer version browser:
My current chrome version is Version 122.0.6261.94. After chrome version 115, no additional driver update is required.
Im running the Pycharm community edition 2023.3.4 on Sonoma 14...

[Error received](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8U4N.png)
[Chrome driver version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFWRX.png)